# Automatic resize QScrollArea

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qscrollarea

I have a scroll area containing a list of checkboxes. I would like this scroll area to resize to the size of the application. Can't figure out how to do this. Any suggestions would be appreciated. I have come this problem in other posts but have not found a solution, or at least a solution I understood.

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class Screen3(QtGui.QWidget):       # Screen to display data

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

        # layout for check box container widget
        chkBoxLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        # create list of checkboxes
        self.checkboxes = []
        numofCheckboxes = 30
        for x in range(numofCheckboxes):
            self.checkboxes.append(QtGui.QCheckBox('test'))
        # add checkboxes to chkBoxLayout
        for i, chkbox in enumerate(self.checkboxes):
            chkbox.setChecked(True)
            chkBoxLayout.addWidget(chkbox)
        chkBoxLayout.addStretch(1) 
        chkBoxLayout.setMargin(0);
        chkBoxLayout.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
        chkBoxLayout.setSpacing(0) 

        # checkbox container widget       
        widget = QtGui.QWidget()  
        widget.setStyleSheet(""".QWidget {background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);}""")
        widget.setLayout(chkBoxLayout)

        # checkbox scroll area, gives scrollable view on widget
        scroll = QtGui.QScrollArea()
        scroll.setMinimumWidth(120)
        scroll.setMinimumHeight(200) # would be better if resizable
        scroll.setWidgetResizable(True)
        scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAsNeeded)
        scroll.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)         
        scroll.setWidget(widget)   

        self.samplePanel = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.samplePanel.addWidget(scroll)
        self.samplePanel.addStretch(1)  

        # horizontal layout
        hbox = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        hbox.addLayout(self.samplePanel)
        hbox.addStretch(1)
        self.setLayout(hbox)
        self.resize(100, 500)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Screen = Screen3()
    Screen.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add the `QScrollArea` to the main layout, you do not need to create other layouts.

```
class Screen3(QtGui.QWidget):       # Screen to display data
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

        # layout for check box container widget
        chkBoxLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        # create list of checkboxes
        self.checkboxes = []
        numofCheckboxes = 30
        for x in range(numofCheckboxes):
            self.checkboxes.append(QtGui.QCheckBox('test'))
        # add checkboxes to chkBoxLayout
        for i, chkbox in enumerate(self.checkboxes):
            chkbox.setChecked(True)
            chkBoxLayout.addWidget(chkbox)
        chkBoxLayout.addStretch(1) 
        chkBoxLayout.setMargin(0);
        chkBoxLayout.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
        chkBoxLayout.setSpacing(0) 

        # checkbox container widget       
        widget = QtGui.QWidget()  
        widget.setStyleSheet(""".QWidget {background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);}""")
        widget.setLayout(chkBoxLayout)

        # checkbox scroll area, gives scrollable view on widget
        scroll = QtGui.QScrollArea()
        scroll.setMinimumWidth(120)
        scroll.setMinimumHeight(200) # would be better if resizable
        scroll.setWidgetResizable(True)
        scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAsNeeded)
        scroll.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)         
        scroll.setWidget(widget)  

        lay = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(scroll)
```

[image]

Comment: Yes this works, but I oversimplified my original code. I also need some buttons which is why I had the QVBoxLayout. Thanks to you answer however I realized that all I need to do is remove the self.samplePanel.addStretch(1)

Comment: Thanks for your help.